# InDesign : Embed text-based company-logo instead of company name in text layer

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm using InDesign and I'd like to use a Text-based Logo instead of Text. Is it possible that I do this within the same Text layer? One of the benefits would be that the image would respond to the formatting (such as text alignment)

> [image]

I'm having two questions:

1. How can I embed an Image like Text in InDesign?
2. Is this a wise thing to do?

The document I'm creating will be printed so it doesn't matter that the image might not be visible on some devices

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Paste it as an inline graphic.
2. Wisdom is in the eye of the beholder and/or client. Only you can figure out if the annoyance of working with an itty-bitty wandering graphic is worth whatever benefit it provides.